# Which port we can use to run IIS other than 80?

Tags: iis, port

IIS does not work when I start applications like Skype since it also uses port 80.

Which port can I use to run IIS other than 80? (8080 does not work)

Comment: You can stop other services, which is using port:80. This link may helps you: http://openguider.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/how-to-solve-port-80-problems-on-windows/

Comment: Change IIS PORT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312136/how-do-i-change-iis-express-8-port-80-to-8080/56802079#56802079

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can run IIS on any port you like, as long as it does not conflict with other applications. I am using 88, 8888 and other easy to remember ports.

You can find the common used port here: [PORT NUMBERS](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), and it is safer to choose an unassigned TCP port.

Quote:

> The Dynamic and/or Private Ports are those from 49152 through 65535

If IIS is working and you have troubles with an ASP.NET applications, those links might be helpful:

- [How to: Configure ASP.NET Applications for an ASP.NET Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kdfe21k.aspx)
- [ASP.NET and IIS Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx)
- [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx)
- [IIS and ASP.NET: The Application Pool](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511)

If you are still having troubles, it would be helpful to provide more information about your environment, the steps taken so far to solve the problem, and retagging the question (append asp.net for example)

Comment: I have changed the TCP/Port for my default web site to "8888", my asp.net applications still does not work. I am using IIS 6.0.

Comment: Thanks buddy. The PORT NUMBERS hyperlink is quite useful. I think we can use any port that is "unassigned".

Answer (score 20):

Well you can disable skype to use port 80. Click tools --> Options --> Advanced --> Connection and uncheck the appropriate checkbox. [image: Skype Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Port 8080 might have been used by another process in your computer.

Do `netstat` in command prompt to find out which server/process is using it.

Have a look at this page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_number) it gives you full explanation on how to use port number

Comment: Skype hijacks port 80 if IIS has not started yet.

Answer (score 5):

Also remember, when running on alternate ports, you need to specify the port on the URL:

http://www.example.com:8080

There may be firewalls or proxy servers to consider depending on your environment.

Answer (score 2):

you can configure IIS in IIS Mgr to use EVERY port between 1 and 65535 as long it is not used by any other application

Comment: can you configure skype like this too? ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Stopping Skype from using port 80: http://forum.skype.com/lofiversion/index.php/t15582.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a few assumptions and come at the problem from a different angle... in that because you have skype installed and running on the same machine, that it is not a production machine and instead used for testing / development?

If so, you may wish to look at alternatives to IIS completely to alleviate your issue. If you use IISExpress or the web server built into recent versions of Visual Studio, they will automatically pick a port for you.

Of course this does mean that it's not particularly useful for giving other people access, but is fine for local development for personal use.

I think the other answers probably offer a better alternative in most situations, but this may offer a different insight.

Here is an intro to IIS Express: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/860/iis-express/

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the port first for example 127.0.0.1:91 then you need to allow access to port 91 
from windows firewall->>advance setting->>inbound rules->> new rule. 
then check port->> assign new port (91). then next to finished.
After this  127.0.0.1:91 should be accessible from the web.