# How do I Change IIS Express 8 port 80 to 8080

Tags: apache, iis-express

I used to use vs2010 and webmatrix. However,I'm trying to use apache lately.
So my IIS express is using port 80 and apache is using port 8080.
I intend to have it the other way around. Let apache use port80 and IIS use 8080.
I couldn't let apache listen to port 80 until IIS no longer listen to port 80.
How should I config IIS express's port?

ps.I'm using win7 with one ip adress

Comment: Nothing really helped me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/change-iis-port-windows/

Answer (score 31):

Try this

To configure the default IIS website to use port 8080

On the Windows desktop, click Start, click Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, in the Connections pane, expand the computer name, expand Sites, and then click Default Web Site.

In the Actions pane, under Edit Site, click Bindings.

In the Site Bindings dialog box, click the http entry, and then click Edit.

In the Edit Site Binding dialog box, in Port, type 8080, and then click OK.

In the Site Bindings dialog box, click Close.

In the Actions pane, under Manage Web Site, click Stop, and then click Start.

Comment: Well...I don't see Internet Information Services (IIS) Manageger in Administrative Tools. I guess it's because I have IIS express instead IIS.

Comment: may be you need to turn on the feature. try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

Add or Remove Programs/ Add and Remove Windows Components / Select the Internet Information Services (IIS)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0

```
 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Select the Web.
 2. site that you wish to configure. In the Action pane, click Bindings.
 3. Click Add to add a new site binding, or click Edit to change an existing binding.
 4. Click OK to apply the changes.
```

Source - [How to change the port for IIS services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605)

Answer (score 2):

How to change IIS port in windows
Posted on November 21, 2017 by Suresh Kamrushi in Windows
[Like] +2
[Unlike] 0
Thanks for your vote.

Showing here, how you can update IIS server port number in windows 10/8 system. There may be several reason you want to change the port but for me its WAMP, I am using it for PHP projects. IIS and WAMP use same port which make trouble developing. So I updated IIS port. You can also update the WAMP port, referring to my blog
Follow the below steps to update IIS server port number:

1. Go start and type IIS
2. IIS Manager will open. click on “Default Web Site” on left hand side.
3. click on “bindings…” from the right side action section.
4. Popup will open with 80 port listed. select it and click the edit button.
5. Update the port and restart the server.

source : http://sforsuresh.in/change-iis-port-windows/

Answer (score 1):

IIS 8.1

1. Select “Default Web Site” from the left tree in IIS manager.
2. Click Bindings from the right sidebar to open a dialog box.
3. Select “http” record from the grid and hit Edit.
4. Enter your choice of port number in “Port” Text box and hit OK.