# How to host Angular 5 to iis under port 86

Tags: angular

I tried to host the Angular 5 application to the IIS follow the guide line [angular to iis](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7). However, look like it only works on the port 80.
Is there any way to host angular 5 to the IIS under the port 86 or any other ports.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43848046/2780943

Comment: I tried to bind to port 86, but it stil not working. The blank page still display. If I change to port 80 again, it works well

Answer (score 0):

check your environment.ts, maybe there is a URL configuration there .. you can change that URL. variable to some thing like mysite:86?