# How to run both Microsoft IIS and WAMP on the same PC via localhost

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, iis, xampp

I have recently enabled IIS by going to the Add/Remove Programs option in the Windows Control Panel and enabled IIS via the “Turn Windows features on or off” checklist.

I also want to install PHP for Windows on the same laptop and have downloaded XAMPP but I have yet to actually install it. Is it possible to do this and run them both from http://localhost/ - or is that not possible?

If so, great stuff... but if not, can you please give me some helpful pointers on how to achieve both IIS and PHP/MySQL running locally from the same PC?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but this is universal: you can only have one server running on one port. The default HTTP port is 80 and the default HTTPS port is 443. If IIS is running on 80 & 443, then WAMP will have to run on another port. To access webservers on another port, you use the address `http://localhost:PORT`.

Comment: I've just posted that comment as an answer because I think it might be helpful for future visitors to this question (comments are removed over time). I've also added a bit of more information and a few links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple servers on one physical machine, but you can only have one server running on one port. The default HTTP port is 80 and the default HTTPS port is 443. If IIS is running on 80 & 443, then WAMP will have to run on another port, and vice-versa. To access web servers on another port, you use the address `http://localhost:PORT`.

To change the ports of either web server see these questions:

- [How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8574332/13376511)
- [How do I Change IIS Express 8 port 80 to 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312136/how-do-i-change-iis-express-8-port-80-to-8080)

Answer (score 3):

In theory, it is possible to run two different web servers in the same machine. The only trick you need to consider for this is adjusting the reach points which are ports.

So the answer of your question is both yes and no. You can run them together in your localhost but if you want to access them both from http://localhost/ it is not possible. you need to provide the ports they've using to do that like http://localhost:5000/

To achieve this, you just need to adjust some settings files in your XAMMP etc. Change the default port and it should work.